# How to structure a multilanguage Website in Django 1.6

Tags: python, django

I’m writing a simple multilanguage website in Django and I struggle a bit with switching languages. I thought it would be good to have different urls for each language (e.g. /en/contact/ for the english site, /de/kontakt/ for the german site). Maybe this does not only look better but does also make sense in the SEO context.

So I have in urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = pattern(‘’,
    url(r’^de/kontakt/$’, mysite.views.DeKontaktView, name=‘kontakt’,),
    url(r’^en/contact/$’, mysite.views.EnContactView, name=‘contact’,),
)
```

Now I’d like to have links on every page (in the base template) to switch the language between german and english. In the Django documentation I found the ‘set_language redirect view’ (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/translation/#the-set-language-redirect-view).

My problem is where and how to tell the view where it should redirect when switching languages. I do not always want to redirect to the frontpage of my site but to the corresponding page in the other language - which has a completely different url - not only a different language prefix in the url.

Since the ‘set_language redirect view’ seems to use the referrer unless there is a next parameter in the post data, my first idea was something like this:

views.py:

```
def EnContactView(request):
    …
    if request.LANGUAGE_CODE == ‘en’:
        return render_to_response(‘en/contact.html’), context)
    else:
        return redirect(‘/de/kontakt/‘)

def DeKontaktView(request):
    …
    if request.LANGUAGE_CODE == ‘de’:
        return render_to_response(‘de/kontakt.html’), context)
    else:
        return redirect(‘/en/contact/‘)
```

But I think this may not be a good solution since this would also redirect depending on the browser language. For example: if someone with browser language ‘en’ visits one of our german urls directly, e.g. via Google. Since there is neither a cookie ‘en’ nor a language choice in the session, the visitor would be redirected to the english url - which is not intended.

So what are the best practices for these situations? To sum up: I have completely different urls for the languages - not only a different language prefix in the url. For every language I do have one template (directories templates/en/ and templates/de/).

- How can I switch between the corresponding pages in different languages?
- and by the way: Is it possible to not use a form as a language switcher but simple links ‘de’ and ‘en’?

It would be great if someone could help me out. The “language thing” is quite confusing for a django noob.

Comment: Why you don't use "Internationalization: in URL patterns" :
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#module-django.conf.urls.i18n ?

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/translation/#translating-url-patterns

```
#setting.py
gettext = lambda s: s

LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', gettext('English')),
    ('de', gettext('De')),

)

#url
from django.http import Http404
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns('',
    url(r'^contact/$', mysite.views.ContactView, name='contact'),
)

#view
def ContactView(request)
    if request.LANGUAGE_CODE == 'de':
        return render_to_response('de/kontakt.html')
    if request.LANGUAGE_CODE == 'en':
        return render_to_response('en/contact.html')
    raise Http404
```

Answer (score 0):

`django.conf.urls.i18n.i18n_patterns` will take care of the language prefix part, `django.views.i18n.set_language` of (most of) the language switching part, and you can use `django.utils.translation.ugettext_lazy` to translate your url patterns just like any other translatable "static" text. You'll still have to handle content's translation one way or another (there are quite a few more or less pluggable apps solving this for Django models), but this part really depends on your application's domain and logic.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more full blown solution for those having problems with translations or are creating a multi-language site.

In settings.py …

Add to MIDDLEWEAR_CLASSES, locale, it enables language selection based on request:

```
'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
```

Add LOCALE_PATHS, this is where your translation files will be stored, also enable i18N:
    USE_I18N = True
    LOCALE_PATHS = (
        os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'locale/'),
    )

Set LANGUAGES that you will be translating the site to:

```
ugettext = lambda s: s
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', ugettext('English')),
    ('fr', ugettext('French')),
    ('pl', ugettext('Polish')),
)
```

Add i18n template context processor, requests will now include LANGUAGES and LANGUAGE_CODE:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.debug',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n', # this one
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',  
)
```

Nest, in urls.py :

In url_patterns, add the below, it will enable the set language redirect view:

```
url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
```

See Miscellaneous in [Translations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/) for more on this.

Add the following imports, and encapsulate the urls you want translated with i18n_patterns. Here is what mine looks like:

```
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
)

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns('',
    (_(r'^dual-lang/'), include('duallang.urls')),
    (r'^', include('home.urls')),
)
```

Note: You can also drop your admin urls into the i18n_patterns.

Now anywhere you use text and want to convert it, import lazytext and wrap every string with it like so _('text'), you can even go to your other urls.py files and do url translation like so:

```
url(_(r'^dual_language/$'), landing, name='duallang_landing'),
```

You can wrap text that you want translated in your other files, such as models.py, views.py etc.. Here is an example model field with translations for label and help_text:

```
name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=255, unique=True, help_text=_("Name of the FAQ Topic"))
```

In your html templates...

Now you can go into your templates and load the i18n templatetag and use trans and transblock on the static stuff you want to translate. Here is an example:

```
{% load i18n %}

{% trans "This is a translation" %}<br><br>
{% blocktrans with book_t='book title'|title author_t='an author'|title %}
This is {{ book_t }} by {{ author_t }}. Block trans is powerful!
{% endblocktrans %}
```

Now run a makemessages for each of your locales:

```
./manage.py makemessages -l pl
```

And now all is left is to go into your /locales folder, and edit each of the .po files. Fill in the data for each msgstr. Here is one such example of that:

```
msgid "English"
msgstr "Angielski"
```

Leave the ones that make sense blank to pick up the default language.

And finally compile the messages:

```
./manage.py compilemessages
```

There is a lot more to learn with translations and [internationalization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/) is closely related to this topic, so check out the docs for it too. I also recommend checking out some of the internationalization packages available for Django like [django-rosetta](https://github.com/mbi/django-rosetta), and [django-linguo](https://github.com/zmathew/django-linguo). They help translate model content, django-rosetta does not create new entries for this in your database, while django-linguo does.

If you followed this you should be off to a good start. I believe this is the most standardized way to get your site running in multiple languages. Cheers!